# Convert AlertDialog to Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I found this nice colorpicker class for android:
https://github.com/jesperborgstrup/buzzingandroid/blob/master/src/com/buzzingandroid/ui/HSVColorPickerDialog.java

It's working very well but it's an AlertDialog class and I want to embed the colorpicker directly in my main layout. 
Has anyone an advice how I could manage that?

Comment: not necessarily easily, but it could be refactored to extend from View (https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html), and then included in your layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at the implementation, It's actually not necessary to be inherited from `AlertDialog`, What you need is just a customised view. Just remove those click listener related part.
Check this [gist](https://gist.github.com/garymabin/3249ea43d6bb7b27fb2b6ea265439259), It's not runnable code, just demonstrate which part can be moved out.

Comment: I got some more issues, but I think I will get it working. Thanks very much.